# Pinning for Sculpt mode

Tags: sculpting

[image: sword with curve]

I wanted to try out the MBall feature to make a sword. Now I want to sculpt its blade. For a better orientation, I took a curve. When I sculpt the outer verts, they always slide away from the blade. Is it somehow possible to activate a option that the outer verts stick to their position?

Thanks.

Comment: I can't tell what exactly do you want to do, but if the question is about preventing some of vertices from moving while sculpting then use masking. Note though that in most cases mask should be drawn manually

Comment: I think, that's exactly what I'm were looking for, Thanks!